# Testing on Hosted TFS?

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild, azure-devops

I just pushed my project up to TFS online (visualstudio.com) for the first time and figured I'd try and run some tests while I'm at it.  I ran them and they failed because I didn't set up a sql database - these tests have only ever run locally.

How does one go about running tests on tfs / configuring sql server?  Do I have to somehow point to a database, something hosted on azure perhaps?

Totally new to this so any references / general tips would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to do some advance build / test, whether it's linking against libraries that aren't installed on the default build agent or setting up a SQL server to test against, then you will almost certainly need to provision your own build agent.

You can still use Team Foundation Service's source control and queueing of continuous integration, and you need not host your own build agent (you can set up an Azure VM).  But if you've outgrown the simple build agent included, you'll need to configure your own.

Comment: Thanks Edward.  I like the idea of running tests against a test database in Azure... perhaps this is better suited for another question, but would it be possible to tell TFS to build and deploy to Azure, and tell Azure to run tests against a sql server I specify?

Comment: I think so!  Azure and TFS can integrate to provide automatic deployment: http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/common-tasks/publishing-with-tfs/

Answer (score 1):

You can attribute you test methods with the [`TestCategoryAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.testcategoryattribute.aspx) and the value of `Database`.

Then [configure your Build Definition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd286595.aspx) to filter only run test that are **not** database. This will stop them running on the Build Server, and just run them locally.

Example Test

```
[TestClass]
public class Test
{
    [TestMethod, TestCategory("Database")]
    public void TestMethod
    {
        Assert.Fail();
    }
}
```

And in your build definition (if you are using the Visual Studio Test Runner):

```
TestCategory!=Database
```

You can set it here:

[image]

Comment: @mwigdahl It appears for me, the source URL is http://i.stack.imgur.com/pYlw1.png

Comment: my bad, apparently blocked by my employer's overzealous web censor... :)

Comment: @mwigdahl No worries, it happens :)